# need help with determinant closed form

Tags: matrices, determinant

For my research, I am looking for the determinant of a square matrix with the form

\begin{bmatrix}
x+1 & 2 & 2 & 1 & \dots & 1 & 1 \\
2 & x+1 & 1 & 2 & \dots & 1 & 1 \\
2 & 1 & x+1 & 1 & \dots & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 1 & x+1 & \dots & 1 & 1 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots & \vdots \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \dots & x+1 & 2 \\
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & \dots & 2 & x+1 \\
\end{bmatrix}

where $x$ is an integer greater than $1$, and the dimension of the matrix is $x^2+x-1.$
For example when $x=2$, the matrix becomes
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 2 & 2 & 1 & 1 \\
2 & 3 & 1 & 2 & 1 \\
2 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 2 \\
1 & 2 & 1 & 3 & 2 \\
1 & 1 & 2 & 2 & 3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
I start by adding every other row to the first, then dividing the now all $(x+1)^2$ row by $(x+1)^2$, so that I can subtract the resulting all-ones row from every other row.
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 2 & 0 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 \\
\end{bmatrix}
After this, I am stuck on what to do for the general case of $x$. Any ideas would be appreciated.